# Entity Framework 6 new records not resolving foreign entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have an issue with some code since upgrading from EF 4 database first (.edmx) to EF 6 code first.

I have a table called Test, and a table called Student. Each student can have many tests, and the tables are joined (studentId is a primary key in "Student", and a foreign key in "Tests").

If I create a new Test in code and then add it to the database, that all works fine. The issue is when I try to read the EF generated Student property.

```
var test = new test { studentId = 4, testName = "My Test", result = "B" };
db.Tests.Add(test);
db.SaveChanges();

var studentName = test.Student.Name;  // this gives an error - Student is null!
```

Under Entity Framework 4, I could add a row as above, and then as soon as I had saved changes, the foreign objects would become available.

Has anything changes in EF 6 with regards to this? The only other alteration is that MARS has also been disabled. Might this be related?

This is a widespread problem for the project, but I'm hoping it's something I can solve easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity class instance is of the entity type `test` and not the proxy that handles lazy loading hence the navigation properties will not lazy load.

Update: try the following to create the entity object w/ proxy

```
var test = db.Tests.Create();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please show me how the code should look when creating a new row? Should the new entity come from the dbcontext?

Comment: That explains it perfectly - thank you very much for helping me out.